# How would you say "to see things from up above" in Latin?

Tags: word-request

There is a song by Tedi Spalato, dedicated to Vinko Coce who had recently died, called "Vidi li se šta odozgar?", which means "Can anything be seen from up above (from heaven)?". How would you say that in Latin? My attempt would be: "Videturne aliquid ab loco supra nos?".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The adverb you are looking for is [*desuper*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddesuper) (or, much more rarely, [*desursum*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddesursum)).

Here's a close parallel from the *Aeneid*:

> Aetheria tum forte plaga crinitus Apollo
> **desuper Ausonias acies urbemque uidebat**
> nube sedens. . . . (IX.638-40)

Translation:

> Then, by chance flowing-haired Apollo, sitting on a cloud in the heavenly region, **saw from above the Ausonian ranks and city.**

On this model, I would translate your phrase as follows:

> Potestne quidquam videri desuper?